# 7bit email gets received as base64

Tags: email, gmail, mutt, plaintext, outlook.com

I am sending an email with mutt from a hotmail address to gmail.

Source on hotmail:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.c"
```

Source on GMail:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; name="file.c"
Content-Description:file.c
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.c"; size=246; creation-date="Tue, 24 Jan 2017 14:00:19 GMT"; modification-date="Tue, 24 Jan 2017 14:00:19 GMT"
Content-ID: <475E95A7ACC9AE43995111143BE55AD8@EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

How is this possible?

Comment: You should avoid calling this 7-bit encoding, considering its simply ASCII, while technically correct nobody woudl reference this file as having a 7-bit charset/encoding.  How is it possible, either the sender/reciever is converting your text to binary, then encoding that has base64.

Comment: @Ramhound Could it be that the hotmail (outlook.com) server does this automatically?

Comment: I have sent thounds of text base files using my Outlook and Google account.  What you describe has never happened to any of those files.

Comment: Hmm, weird... well these are the email source files, I haven't changed anything :/